# how to display data to the text field when the marker is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm using SQL to show marker to leaflet and How can I output the data of a marker into the input text field when the marker is clicked.

(https://milzon.site/web/home.php)

this my script

```
<div id="map">
            <script>
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: [-7.54071750000000000, 110.44572410000000000],
                    zoom: 7
                }
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    getUsers();
                    getInfo();
                });
                var map = new L.map('map', mapOptions);
                var layer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
                map.addLayer(layer);
                function getUsers() {
                    $.getJSON("getData.php", function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);
                            var name = data[i].nama_lokasi;
                            var longitude = data[i].longitude;
                            var latitude = data[i].latitude;
                            var marker = L.marker([data[i].lat, data[i].lng]).addTo(map);
                            marker.bindPopup(name);
                        }
                    })


                }

            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"  >
    <label style="padding-right: 1em; float: left; text-align: right; width: 15%;">Nama Lokasi : </label><input type="text" style="width: 800px; overflow:  ; " readonly value= "" /><br>
    <label style="padding-right: 1em; float: left; text-align: right; width: 15%">Alamat : </label><input type="text" style="width: 800px; overflow:  ; " readonly/><br>
    <label style="padding-right: 1em; float: left; text-align: right; width: 15%">Longitude : </label><input type="text" style="width: 800px; overflow:  ; " readonly/><br>
    <label style="padding-right: 1em; float: left; text-align: right; width: 15%">Latitude : </label><input type="text" style="width: 800px; overflow:  ; " readonly/><br>
    <label style="padding-right: 1em; float: left; text-align: right; width: 15%">Core Info : </label><input type="text" style="width: 800px; overflow:  ; " readonly/><br>
    <label style="padding-right: 1em; float: left; text-align: right; width: 15%">Route Info : </label><input type="text" style="width: 800px; overflow:  ; " readonly/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Fellow Indonesian

hopefully i can help you in some ways

as far as i know leaflet.js let you set an event listener to the marker object.
so basically all you need to do is

1. give id to all your target input on the html
2. set "click" event listener to the marker
3. update the target input based on id

check my snippet..

have a nice day

**HTML**

```
<label style="padding-right: 1em; float: left; text-align: right; width: 15%;">Nama Lokasi : </label>

<!-- give an id  -->
<input id="nama" type="text" style="width: 800px; overflow:  ; " readonly value="" /><br>

<label style="padding-right: 1em; float: left; text-align: right; width: 15%">Longitude : </label>

<!-- give an id  -->
<input id="longitude" type="text" style="width: 800px; overflow:  ; " readonly/><br>

<label style="padding-right: 1em; float: left; text-align: right; width: 15%">Latitude : </label>

<!-- give an id  -->
<input id="latitude" type="text" style="width: 800px; overflow:  ; " readonly/><br>
```

**JS**

```
$.getJSON("getData.php", function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);
    var name = data[i].nama_lokasi;
    var longitude = data[i].longitude;
    var latitude = data[i].latitude;
    var marker = L.marker([data[i].lat, data[i].lng]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup(name);

    // add event onclick to the markers
    marker.on('click', function(name, longitude, latitude) {
      $("#name").val(name)
      $("#longitude").val(longitude)
      $("#latitude").val(latitude)
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: just appeared    " [object Object] " in  top field text :(